# A single word for the emotion of "relocation depression"

Tags: single-word-requests

It's a term used to describe the feeling after you've relocated somewhere else, whether it be from a move to another city/country, a change in jobs to somewhere else, or a shift in lifestyle.  I was wondering if there's a single word to describe the emotion some feel when experiencing relocation depression. When I finished my Bachelor's I felt a small sense of it, but I could not come up with the words to describe it, other than this term I found online.

Is there a single word that could describe the emotion felt when under "relocation depression"?

Comment: Mm.. homesickness?

Comment: Homesickness implies distress when away from home. But when your home has moved, and there's still this lingering sadness over changing, it's not really homesickness I'd say.

Comment: How about retrospection? "A survey of past or recent experiences."

Comment: *Nostalgia* seems pretty close.

Comment: I would say "homesickness" also. I think it is applicable, but you have viewed the problem from the new location rather than the leaving of home. You are sad about being where you are rather than where you were.

Answer (score 1):

Relocation depression could be caused by many factors, i.e. trying to adjust yourself to new environment, fear of interacting with strangers and pressure to prove yourself to them, etc.

*Relocation depression* could be called *Anxiety*, more specifically *Stranger Anxiety* or *Social Anxiety*.

> **Anxiety** is not the same as fear, which is a response to a real or perceived immediate threat;[4] whereas anxiety is the expectation of future threat. Anxiety is a feeling of fear, uneasiness, and worry, usually generalized and unfocused as an overreaction to a situation that is only subjectively seen as menacing...
>
> **Anxiety** during social interactions, particularly between **strangers**, is
> common among young people. It may persist into adulthood and become
> **social anxiety** or social phobia. **Stranger anxiety** in small children
> is not considered a phobia. In adults, an excessive fear of other
> people is not a developmentally common stage; it is called **social
> anxiety**. According to Cutting, social phobics do not fear the
> crowd but the fact that they may be judged negatively.

[Source: Wikipedia article on [anxiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiety)]

Answer (score 0):

Culture shock - the feeling of disorientation experienced by someone who is suddenly subjected to an unfamiliar culture, way of life, or set of attitudes.

Comment: you may want to visit the site's help center to read about how to provide "good" answers. Notably, it's customary to include sources for definitions, word origins, grammar rules, etc.

Comment: When I returned to the country where I was born after living for many, many years in another country and even taking dual citizenship, I used to speak of _reverse culture shock_.